# How to draw a plane in 3D perspective on an image using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, rectangles, plane

I need to define a plane using the equation ax + by + cz + d = 0, and draw it on an image using a translucent rectangle with gridlines in 3D perspective.

I know what values I need to use for a, b, c and d, but can't find any sample code which demonstrates how use those values to draw a plane on the image in perspective.

I can find examples of drawing a flat rectangle in 2D on the image, or creating a rotating 3D rectangle using cv::viz, but not for drawing a plane on an existing image.

Comment: You'd need to know the perspective you want too. Camera position, field of view,...

Comment: Have a look at virtual camera models and pinhole camera projection. Basically you will need to define camera intrinsics 
(how does the image plane look like) + extrinsics(where is the camera posed in 3d space) and then you can use simple mathematics to project a 3d point to that plane. Use OpenGL or Open3D if you can use additional libraries.

Comment: Yes I have computed the camera intrinsics and extrinsics using the checkerboard calibration, and have the rotation and translation vectors. And I have looked at the material you have suggested but it's quite difficult to come up with an example. I would think this would be an OpenCV entry-level example in a tutorial somewhere, but I can't find a single example of drawing a plane in space and rotating it.